# JavaFX going back to a previous stage and then making an action crash the application

Tags: java, javafx

I'm having problems with a simple application, in one Stage I've got a Login screen, when user enters a valid username & password it leads to another Stage, in Stage2 I've a button to close session that takes you back to the login Stage, the problem is that if I try to login again the application stops working (in the console there're no errors) .

Here are my codes:

**Login.class**

```
public class DocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button btn_login;
    @FXML
    private TextField et_username;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField et_password;
    @FXML
    private Hyperlink link_signup;
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane ap_login;


    public void login() throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Login");
        Stage stageRegister = (Stage) ap_login.getScene().getWindow();
        Connector conn = new Connector();

        if (conn.checkUser(et_username.getText(), et_password.getText())) {

            System.out.println("1");

            Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(DocumentController.class);
            prefs.put("username", et_username.getText());
            prefs.put("password", et_password.getText());

            System.out.println("2");

            TaskerController controler = new TaskerController();
            controler.setUser(et_username.getText());
            FXMLLoader task = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/FXMLTasker.fxml"));

            System.out.println("3");

            task.setController(controler);
            System.out.println("3.1");
            Pane pane = task.load();

            System.out.println("4");

            Scene taskScene = new Scene(pane);
            Stage taskStage = new Stage();
            taskStage.setOnCloseRequest(t -> System.exit(0));

            System.out.println("5");


            taskStage.setScene(taskScene);
            taskStage.setTitle("Tasks");
            stageRegister.close();
            taskStage.show();
        } else {
           Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
           alert.setTitle("Error");
           alert.setHeaderText("Information Alert");
           String s ="Usuario o Contraseña incorrecta";
           alert.setContentText(s);
           alert.show();
        }
    }

    public void register() throws IOException {
        Stage stageRegister = (Stage) ap_login.getScene().getWindow();

        FXMLLoader createTask = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/FXMLRegister.fxml"));
        Pane pane = createTask.load();
        Scene createTaskScene = new Scene(pane);
        Stage createTaskStage = new Stage();
        createTaskStage.setScene(createTaskScene);
        createTaskStage.setTitle("Register");
        stageRegister.close();
        createTaskStage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        if (btn_login == event.getSource()) {
            login();
        } else if (link_signup == event.getSource()) {
            register();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(DocumentController.class);

        et_username.setText(prefs.get("username", "Introduce el nombre de "));
        et_password.setText(prefs.get("password", "123"));

        Platform.runLater(() -> et_username.requestFocus());

    }

}
```

**Method on the other Stage that goes back to Login.class**

```
@FXML
void cerrar_sesion() throws IOException {
    Stage stageRegister = (Stage) ap_tasker.getScene().getWindow();

    Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(DocumentController.class);
    prefs.put("username", "");
    prefs.put("password", "");

    FXMLLoader login = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/FXMLLogin.fxml"));
    Pane pane = (Pane) login.load();
    Scene loginScene = new Scene(pane);
    Stage loginStage = new Stage();
    loginStage.setScene(loginScene);
    loginStage.setTitle("Login");
    loginStage.setOnCloseRequest((WindowEvent t) -> System.exit(0));
    stageRegister.close();
    loginStage.show();
}
```

I've found that the aplication stops working when it reaches this line in Login.class:

```
Pane pane = task.load();
```

Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: Start by removing all the `JOptionPane`s from your code, and replacing them with JavaFX `Alert`s. On many systems, trying to show a swing window from the FX Application thread will cause deadlock. That may help you at least diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I corrected it, I think that the program is in an infinite loop, and that's why  it breaks. But I've no idea why goes around looping the second time but the firts not.

Comment: My guess is that the `initialize` method of `TaskerController` is the cause of the issue. However `FXMLLoader` can many kinds of objects. Without more info about what the fxml/controller looks like it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Do you also assign a controller in the .fxml file?

Comment: Nope, the strange thing is the first time works, but then when I change the scene back it dosn't.

Comment: Might have something to do with `/view/FXMLLogin.fxml`. The file could has a syntax error.

Comment: Simply throwing a bounty at this question is not going to make it possible for anyone to answer it. The reason it hasn't had enough attention is that you haven't provided enough information for anyone to know what is wrong. Create, from scratch if necessary, a [MCVE] and edit the question to include it.

Comment: Could there be a problem with the resources associated with "/view/FXMLLogin.fxml" already being in use? Login works the first time, so you know there isn't a typo or anything. When you go back to Login the second time, your application crashes at task.load(); This makes me wonder if you are exiting the Login stage properly and releasing all resources the first time you go to Stage2.